# Will "addValueChangeListener" cause memory leak?

Tags: memory-leaks, listener, vaadin

I am using a tree within the left panel and a detail view (VerticalLayout with labels and buttons) within the right panel. Each node contains extensive data, that are saved by this way:

```
IndexedContainer nodeData;
.
.
.
tree.getContainerDataSource()
    .getContainerProperty(itemId, "nodeData").setValue(nodeData)
```

The content for selected node is displayed in detail view. It can be modified using a modal window (clicking "Edit" button in detail view).

I am using nodeData.addValueChangeListener(detailView). The detail view implements function for updating its own content when the modal window saves nodeData.

It works fine, but I have worries about memory leak. The right panel content (detailView) is destroyed when I select another node. Another view can be placed on the same place, because the nodeData of another node can have another structure. But nodeData container lives for long time and I can select it more times. My question is:

**Does it cause memory leak? Or the system is able to remove unaccessible object that are referenced only as a listener?**

Thank you for telling me, if it can be problem. Any advices are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't worry about a memory leak in this case, as the listener is being injected into the component.
You can detect if there is a memory leak or not from the server, for instance, stopping Tomcat server will through some memory leak errors in the logs if there is a memory leak or any unreachable objects.

However, I would recommend overriding the detach() method on your tree to make sure you cleanup your resources once a view or a component is detached from the screen/view.

Comment: Unfortunately the mem-leak exists. F.e. I need to refresh my Label: nodeData.addValueChangeListener(myLabel); the label (in a Layout) function valueChanged(event) is fired even if the Layout doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved. It is possible to check out the component from listening changes, when it is orphaned:

```
if(!isAttached()) 
   nodeData.removeValueChangeListener(this);
```